# Fnd a way to work with porter stemmer and encoding in python

Tags: python-2.7, encoding, ascii, porter-stemmer

I tried to read file and use *PorterStemmer* to store stem tokens of the files' text and I got this error.

```
    tokens=preprocessTokens(line)
    File "/home/fl/git/KNN/preprocessDoc.py", line 20, in preprocessTokens
line=line+' '+ps.stem(w)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/stem/porter.py", line 664, in stem
    stem = self._step1a(stem)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/stem/porter.py", line 289, in _step1a
   if word.endswith('ies') and len(word) == 4:
   UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

To solve it add these two line to my code and then ignore

```
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('ISO-8859-15')
```

But I got the following error for some of files. Then I try to change encoding  to 'utf-8'I and I got same error.

```
tokens=preprocessTokens(line.encode('ascii',errors='ignore'))
  File "/home/fl/git/KNN/preprocessDoc.py", line 20, in preprocessTokens
    line=line+' '+ps.stem(w)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/stem/porter.py", line 665, in stem
    stem = self._step1b(stem)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/stem/porter.py", line 376, in _step1b
    lambda stem: (self._measure(stem) == 1 and
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/stem/porter.py", line 258, in _apply_rule_list
    if suffix == '*d' and self._ends_double_consonant(word):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/stem/porter.py", line 214, in _ends_double_consonant
    word[-1] == word[-2] and
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is having problems with character values greater than 127. So, as a workaround I take the input string character-by-character and AND that character with 127 (ie: c & 127) then put that character back into the string. In other words rebuild the string and force every character to be translated under 127 ascii then proceed to process that input string
This is a solution that I find for my problem.